# Zookeeper recommendation for clustered Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

What's the general recommendation for running Zookeeper in a clustered NiFi? Use the embedded or external Zookeeper? Starting from scratch so no existing Zookeeper running....

Answer (score 8):

The embedded ZooKeeper provided with Apache NiFi is for ease of use getting started and can be used for some light use cases, but for a serious production flow with a high volume of data, you should use an external ZooKeeper.

Comment: Thank you! I went ahead and setup and external Zookeeper cluster.